# Can not find attribute app:useSimpleSummaryProvider

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-preferences

I want to update my preference summary and I found something called SimpleSummaryProvider [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/customize-your-settings). But In my case, it's saying that cannot find attribute `app:useSimpleSummaryProvider` and in Java code, it's saying, cannot resolve SummaryProvider class. My app level build Gradle dependencies are as-

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
```

I don't know if I am missing something.
I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`app:useSimpleSummaryProvider` is newly added in the `androidx.preference 1.1.0-alpha01` according to [AndroidX release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn)(search `app:useSimpleSummaryProvider` in the page).

So you need to migrate to AndroidX and update to the latest alpha version of androidx.

Answer (score 0):

change implementation `'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'`to
implementation `'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'` it will be ok.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference#1.2.0