# How to use the "useSimpleSummaryProvider" in the preferences for android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to implement some preferences (settings) into my app and that did work. Additionally, I want to display the *value* of the current preference as it's *summary*.

My solution for this problem is to use the "[SimpleSummaryProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/EditTextPreference.SimpleSummaryProvider)" in the preferences.xml file, as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53722223). This solution does not throw an error and also works in the preview. However, in the compiled app, there simply is no summary at all.

[image]

To reproduce this error:

Android Studio -> Empty Activity

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.test.simplesummary;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.idFrameLayout, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences);

        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/idFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

root_preferences.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory>
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="test_key"
            android:title="test_title"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
            />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.test.simplesummary'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.simplesummary"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}
```

Comment: Did I add the minimal reproducible example correctly? @dbc

Comment: Looks good in my opinion.